# Что означает это выражение int *(*tab())[45];?

Tags: c

Получил вопрос обьяснить, что это за код(выражение)

```
int *(*tab())[45];
```

Насколько я вижу это какой то метод `tab()` который возвращает ссылку на array(скорее всего int-ов) вот тут мы получаем сам array `*tab()` , а вот тут `*(*tab())` **наверное** доступ к самим значениям и потом как будто просим элемент по 45му индексу вот здесь `int *(*tab())[45];`

Но я очень не уверен в этом

Так вот вопрос в том, что означает это выражение int *(*tab())[45];?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ```
> int *(*tab())[45];
> ```

Это объявление функции, возвращающей указатель на массив из 45 указателей на `int`.
Определить её можно, например, так:

```
int *(*tab())[45] {
    static int *rv[45];
    return &rv;
}
```

На практике такие выражения почти никогда не используют, так что они фактически являются просто головоломками для тех кто думает, что знает Си. Как это читать описано в многочисленных букварях и статьях, в частности [вот одна из гугла](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html) и её [перевод с хабры](https://habr.com/ru/post/116255/).